# What would be the Candidate key (s) of this relation?

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

R(ABCDEPG)

F={AB->CD, DE->P, C->E, P->C, B->G}

To my consideration, the candidate keys are: AB, AG, CD, DE.

Am I correct? Why or why not?

Comment: A demonstration that each of those is correct and/or incorrect per the definition of CK is not the same as a procedure to do that for an arbitrary putative CK or a procedure to generate the CKs given a schema and FDs. If you ever want to answer a different similar question then you need such a procedure. It will constitue a section of a chapter of a textbook introducing FDs, CKs and normalization. Read one.

Comment: @philipxy, then how did JB-Learner answer?

Comment: See whether you can extract from their answer a procedure that works for any schema, FDs and putative CK. Let alone that comes up with all and only CKs. PS It doesn't even explain why AB is a CK. PPS I asked you why you thought certain sets were CKs or not so you would ask yourself what definitions, rules and procedures you were using. Or weren't. Or should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I have mistaken the question, your response of candidate keys is incorrect.

Candidate Key AB:
AB -> CD, C->E, DE->P, B -> G. This is a candidate key.

Candidate Key AG:
A, G, and AG have no inherent relations. Just because B->G doesn't mean that G->B (a similar mistake was made after assuming B was solved and getting the columns of A and B). This is not a candidate key.

Candidate Key CD/DE:
This is not a candidate key. There is no possible way for F to have a candidate key that does *not* include A, as there is no way to determine A without it being part of the key. Similarly, nothing implies B and thus it is required to be part of any candidate key.

Since AB is a candidate key, there is no reason to go further. Any candidate key must include AB and AB is a candidate key, therefore **the only candidate key is `AB`**. A and B must both be supplied as part of the key or else there can be no unique identifiers to their values. Since keys are typically generated with the intent to use the least information possible to determine uniqueness, AB being required for row uniqueness, and AB being a potential key then you can select it as your primary composite key and move on.